# PHP login system doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

I'm making a login system with PHP, but it doesn't work properly

This is my login page:

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" action="index.php?page=login">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="loginFormInputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="loginFormInputEmail" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="loginFormInputPass" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Pass:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="loginFormInputPass" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="login" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here I have the Usercontroller file where I put my login system:

```
public function login() {
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
      if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $existing = $this->userDAO->selectByEmail($_POST['email']);
        if(!empty($existing)) {
          if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $existing['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $existing;
          } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
          }
        } else {
          $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
        }
      } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
      }
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
  }
```

The thing is that if I go to my login page, it automatically goes back to the index page, because I have the location: index.php. But I have no idea how to change this to make it work.

Comment: This part of your code is not to the right place : 

header('Location: index.php');
exit();

You does to put it in your test with the error session variable like 

$_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
header('Location: index.php');
    exit();

Comment: you're executing header('Location: index.php'); after the POST check. It will go to the index.php page. what are you trying to do? what do you mean it doesn't work properly. why do you have an exit in the code? it will stop the script.

Comment: I guess you want it to redirect to index.php regardless, just have different messages, or have the auth'd user in the $_SESSION? If that's the case... what is the issue you are having..?   If it isn't then the above two comments should see you right...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a header() when you validate the user. A header to go wherever you should go when the user has passed your validation.

```
public function login() {
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
      if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $existing = $this->userDAO->selectByEmail($_POST['email']);
        if(!empty($existing)) {
          if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $existing['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $existing;

            header('Location: some_where_else.php');
            // dont forget the exit as header does not stop the flow of execution
            exit;


          } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
          }
        } else {
          $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
        }
      } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unknown username / password';
      }
    }
    // This is now run only when validation failed
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```